# Problems converting UITableViewController to plain UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I"m having some issues trying to manually convert a `UITableViewController` to a plain `UIViewController`.  I need to change some of the layout of the view, so I'm just planning on creating a UITableView manually and positioning it on the screen myself.

I deleted the automated xib file that was generated by default from the project creation process.  I changed the view controller to subclass `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController` as well and have it set adhere to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.

I also set a `UITableview *tableView` property & synthesizer, but I did not manually `alloc` or `addSubview` with it.

However, when I launch the app and the view loads, the tableView still shows on the screen.  I just don't understand how this is happening.

There has to be some kind of vestigal code that was created automatically that I'm not finding and need to clear out, but I've looked through all the related files (app delegate, view controllers, xibs, etc...) and I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I had that problem once because my initWithNibName code had been copy-pasted, and I was using a different nib file, that's about all I can think of that would do that. As a side note, why not just start form a plain UIViewController and add in the table instead?

Comment: @alex-gosselin  I dont have an initWithNibName method in my code anywhere, and this is an old, legacy app for a client that was initially started as a navigation based, table view app.  So the project template setup a nav controller + root view controller (table view) combo automatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in nib file also. Try changing nib files connection.

Comment: as I said, I completely deleted the associated XIB file.  it doesnt even exist anymore

Comment: try "clear project" or manually delete build-folder. compiled xibs (nibs) tend to linger around there for a while; and completely remove app from simulator / testing device.